# Redirect subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking to move `http://domain.com/blog` to `http://blog.domain.com`.This also means that everything that trails `/blog` for example `/blog/post/1` will need to be routed to `http://blog.domain.com/post/1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure that you've got content on `blog.domain.com`. Specifically, if you go to `http://blog.domain.com/post/1` you get served the correct content.
2. In the htaccess file in your `domain.com` domain's document root, add (preferably above any rules you may already have there):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   ```
3. If you actually don't have any content at `blog.domain.com` and it shares the same document root as `domain.com`, then you'll need to add these additional rules:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog%{REQUEST_URI} -d
   RewriteRule ^ /blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
   ```